# Keep target element open when mouse leaves the invoking element and stays on target element

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I want the target element to be visible even after the mouse leaves the element which invoked the process. Lets assume, on hovering over A, B appears. I want B to still be visible when mouse exits A but hovers on B.
Something similar when hovered over phone picture: https://buy.mazumamobile.com/all-products

Below is the code:

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
$(".flyout").hide();

$("#Products").hover(function () {
        $("#productList ").show();
}),
    $(".flyout").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#productList ").show();
    });
$(".flyout").mouseleave(function() {
    $(" #productList").hide();
});
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
}

.flyout {
    position: absolute;
    width: 900px;
    min-height: 450px;
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #E9ECEF;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px gray;
    background-color:red;
}

.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#" id="Products" name="Products">Text</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="productList" class="container flyout">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4>Content</h4>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li>
                        Content
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       Content
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Content
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Content
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4>Content</h4>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks everyone for their help, I have updated code and it now works as how I wanted

Comment: Appears that you're using `id` (Products) for list items which could be multiple. Please replace it with `class` or make sure each id for every element is unique.

Comment: Id products is only one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keep div open until the mouse leave the div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52705836/keep-div-open-until-the-mouse-leave-the-div)

Comment: Do not post the same question multiple times. If the answers do not help, comment on them to ask for clarification or improve your question to make your requirements clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think, You did silly mistake because you hide the same class for mouse leave and mouse out.

> You can use the mouse enter and mouse leave event from JavaScript otherwise you can use the Jquery method such as below.

```
  $(".flyout").mouseenter(function(){
     $("use the div  selector but not use the above class ").show();
  });
  $(".flyout").mouseleave(function(){
       $(" use the div  selector but not use the above class").hide();
 })
```

Comment: Yup :) ok I'm changing

Comment: Hi @Raman Kumar  thanks that helped point me in right direction

Answer (score 1):

You can use the toggle from jQuery to achieve your result.

```
$('#Products').hover(function(){
    $('#productList').toggle();
  console.log('shown');
});
```

Also - you have two hidden css definitions. Change this to one

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Hi @alpharomeo I removed the css hidden

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make use of extensive CSS and use and `addClass()` function.

You can simply make use of the `hide()` function when the element is initially loaded, and then make use of the `toggle()` function on your element. That will switch between a show/hide state depending on its current state.

Since you want this functionality to revolve around hovering over your link element, you need to use a selector relevant to that for your `mouseover` and `mouseout` function. In your case, the relevant selector would be the *id* `Products`.

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.flyout').hide();
    $('#Products').mouseover(function () {
  $('.flyout').toggle();
    }),
    $('#Products').mouseout(function() {
  $('.flyout').toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
}

.flyout {
    position: absolute;
    width: 900px;
    min-height: 450px;
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #E9ECEF;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px gray;
    background-color:red;
}

.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#" id="Products" name="Products">Text</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="productList" class="container flyout">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4>Content</h4>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li>
                        Content
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       Content
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Content
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Content
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4>Content</h4>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```